# Print to PDF into a specific folder

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, windows-services

We have a new windows service that can automatically print results that it receives.  I need to get it to print them to PDF and store them in a specific folder on the server.

It doesn't download the results to a file, but an internal database, so scripting a print is out of the question.  It has to be done via the windows print, but as it's a service, there will be no one to indicate where to save the PDF.

What i'm after is a windows printer service that can print to PDF without asking the end user anything, and have it drop into a folder of my choosing (possibly via print settings, or anything really).

Thanks.

Comment: Who developed this service that prints results that it receives? Do you have the source code to this service? What language is it written with exactly? Adjusting the service to import results to the table and also exporting to a PDF file to a local drive on the server may be a method to consider. Otherwise, what type of a database is it these records get dumped to (e.g. SQL Server, etc.)?

Comment: It's closed source used by a pathology company to download results.  The type of data base is unknown too, it's all internal (no SQL server).

Comment: What is the plan to get the data exported to a file to then be converted to PDF or whatever? You say you have a **"windows service that can automatically print results that it receive"** so where is it printing these results to, the DB table or something? Can you attach a screen shot or something to clarify? You say **"It doesn't download the results to a file, but an internal database"** so I'm wondering how you are going to access the content to print or save to a PDF file? How are you accessing it now that you do know about? I may be totally confused so pardon me if that's the case.

Comment: This is the settings page: http://imgur.com/a/OTH7N
I was planning on using one of those print to PDF printers (such has cutePDF) which can create a PDF file from a windows print.  Sorry if I have been confusing too.